# ITHit webdav EditDoc js not working in ios browsers

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We have used ITHit ajax library to open documents from browser using EditDocument javascript method. (ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument)

All works fine in desktop browsers.(Safari/Chrome/IE/Firefox)

But when we try from IPhone/IPad browsers, the javascript method is invoked but the document opening is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the IT Hit WebDAV Ajax Library runs both in mobile and desktop web browsers, it supports document editing in desktop web browsers only.

It is using components installed by Microsoft Office (in case of MS office docs and if MS Office is found) or Java applet in all other cases to mount a drive and than to open a document. Unfortunately iOS, Android and Win Phone does not provide drive mounting capabilities.

Many mobile applications has built-in WebDAV support. For example [here](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/ipad_iwork) you can find how to open documents in iWork on iOS.